# Terraform: Specify specific Docker Network Name for Output

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-docker

I have a Containerized Network Function (CNF) that connects to three Docker Networks:

```
    ...
    ip_address        = "172.17.0.3"
    ip_prefix_length  = 16
    ipc_mode          = "private"
    log_driver        = "json-file"
    log_opts          = {}
    logs              = false
    max_retry_count   = 0
    memory            = 4096
    memory_swap       = -1
    must_run          = true
    name              = "c-router-52"
    network_data      = [
        {
            gateway          = "172.17.0.1"
            ip_address       = "172.17.0.3"
            ip_prefix_length = 16
            network_name     = "bridge"
        },
        {
            gateway          = "172.31.0.1"
            ip_address       = "172.31.0.4"
            ip_prefix_length = 16
            network_name     = "inside-net"
        },
        {
            gateway          = "172.30.0.1"
            ip_address       = "172.30.0.3"
            ip_prefix_length = 16
            network_name     = "outside-net"
        },
    ]
    network_mode      = "default"
    ...
```

And I am trying to grab the 'outside-net' IP address for use as an input for another container. I am specifying like so:

```
${docker_container.c-router-52.network_data[2].ip_address}
```

When its the third element, it works fine.... But the problem is that Terraform (or Docker, one of the two) doesn't always put the 'outside-net' as the third network :(

Is there a way to specify the [network_name="outside-net"] rather than an index number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code example isn't complete I'm having to guess a little here, but it seems like what you want is a mapping from network name to IP address. You can derive such a data structure from your resource configuration using a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions), which you can assign to a [local value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) for use elsewhere in the configuration:

```
locals {
  container_ip_addresses = {
    for net in docker_container.c-router-52.network_data :
    net.network_name => net.ip_address
  }
}
```

With the above definition in your module, you can refer to `local.container_ip_addresses` elsewhere in your module to refer to this mapping, such as `local.container_ip_addresses["outside-net"]` to access the `outside-net` address in particular.

With the `network_data` structure you showed in your configuration, `local.container_ip_addresses` would have the following value:

```
{
  bridge      = "172.17.0.3"
  inside-net  = "172.31.0.4"
  outside-net = "172.30.0.3"
}
```

If you need to access the other attributes of those `network_data` objects, rather than just the `ip_address`, you can generalize this by making the values of the mapping be the full network objects:

```
locals {
  container_networks = {
    for net in docker_container.c-router-52.network_data :
    net.network_name => net
  }
}
```

...which would then allow you to access all of the attributes via the network name keys:

```
local.container_networks["outside-net"].ip_address
local.container_networks["outside-net"].gateway
local.container_networks["outside-net"].ip_prefix_length
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!  Better than the actual Terraform doc page you pointed me to :)